# Parsing Javascript HTML with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: javascript, c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to get the value of `"Title"` and `"CustomerID"` from this script that's in an HTML document

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    //blablabla
    
   if (app) {
   app.value("onlineUser", {"Id":171454371,"Username":"User9007","BourseCode":"ع اط84408","CustomerId":171273228,"IsTrader":false,"IsForTest":false,"Title":"name","CanTradeForAll":false,"PasswordExpired":false,"CcmsCode":7876016,"ClubCustomerLevel":0,"PasswordSecurityWarnningMode":false,"UserSettings":[{"Key":"marketWatchColumnSettings","Value":"[]"},{"Key":"layoutModeClass","Value":""},{"Key":"showIntro","Value":"false"},{"Key":"newVersion","Value":"2.47.3"},{"Key":"helpDownloaded","Value":"true"},{"Key":"changeLayout","Value":"0"},{"Key":"closeRightBar","Value":"1"},{"Key":"openLeftBar","Value":"0"},{"Key":"selectedTheme","Value":""},{"Key":"orderInfoBoxOptionState","Value":"{\"colState\":[{\"colId\":\"0\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":65,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":\"right\",\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"DateTime\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":183,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"InstrumentName\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"OrderSideId\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"Quantity\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"TradedQuantity\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"RemainingQuantity\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"Price\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"HeadLinePrice\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"OrderState\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":181,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null},{\"colId\":\"1\",\"hide\":false,\"aggFunc\":null,\"width\":90,\"pivotIndex\":null,\"pinned\":null,\"rowGroupIndex\":null}],\"sortState\":[{\"colId\":\"Price\",\"sort\":\"asc\"}]}"},{"Key":"sendOrderConfirmation","Value":"0"}],"FeatureAccess":["Hm01","Po01","Po02","Po03","Po04","Po05"],"HasShortSaleOwner":false,"PersonageTypeId":0,"IsForeign":false,"ActiveTypicalMessageIds":[],"CustomerInitialInstrumentIds":[]});
                app.value("liveAsset", []);
            }

            //blablabla
    
        </script>
```

Is it possible with the help of html agility pack? if not what other tools do I need

Answer (score 0):

No, HTML Agility Pack does not parse `Javascript`. It only supports HTML parsing. To parse `Javascript` you would need an another method like `regex`, `js grammar` etc.